# What would happen if I ll over 600 folders at once?

Tags: linux, debian

I have an old dual core atom server with 4GB of RAM. I found all the git folders on the server with `find / -name ".git"` command and put over 600 lines of these git folders (output) in a file. Now I want to ll all those lines with `ll $(<lines.txt)` but I am not sure If that can crash the server.

Comment: is it a production server?

Comment: and also, why do we need to list-down all of the `.git` folder?

Comment: Note that "folders" is a Windows-ism. On Unix-like systems, they are "directories" which are not the same thing.

Comment: @Rob I think you are right that "directory" would be more appropriate to use in UNIX context. But generally I would say that both are the same file system concept, isn't it?

Comment: @hek2mgl A directory is one where contents can be indexed and often have their own index file. It's a logical construct whereas a folder is a GUI concept where one visualizes a holder of documents. On UNIX and UNIX-like systems, the term folder is rarely used and, especially in this case, it's a logical concept and not a GUI one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not crash the server, but it might take long depending on the number of files in those directories. If they aren't overly full of files, it might just take a few seconds or a minute. (this is very likely).

It will cause IO load and probably cause re-adjusting of Linux IO buffers (depending on their size and state). Both shouldn't be a problem unless the server is under extreme and performance critical load.

I recommend to use:

```
find / -type d -name ".git" -exec ls -al {} +
```

or

```
find / -type d -name ".git" -exec ls -alF  --group-directories-first {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to log it directly to a `txt` file.

```
find / -name ".git" > output-filename.txt
```

You can see [this reference](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-save-ouput-of-linux-unix-command-to-file/).

Before you are going to do that :

1. Is it a production server? (since it has a small RAM)
2. If it is a producttion server :

   - Do not do it on your server's productive hour (the time when peoples are using it actively)